# how to find a duplicate value between two files and print

Tags: perl, awk

I have two files, one with a single IP address (which I have already used perl to strip the ip) and one that has ip's with more info. I need to do a commpare or use perl and find the duplicate IP in each file. but I need the second file with more info to remain in tact and when a duplicate is found print the entire line of the second file.

**file1 content example (just ip no comma etc)**

```
114.42.141.131
```

**file2 content example (need all this info to print when match found)**

```
114.42.141.131,Host TW,Taipei,25.0391998291,121.525001526
```

This is a little beyond my skills. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Thank you!

Comment: if duplicates were found 3 times in file1, print same line from file2 3 times or only once? are there duplicated ips in file2 too? how to handle if yes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match on the first field, all you need is:

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR { a[$1]; next } $1 in a' file1 file2
```

Comment: That worked!!!! THANK YOU!!!!!!! I swear this is the best SITE! You guys are the best!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have shell access.

If the first file contains only the IP, then you can do something like:

```
REF_IP=`cat file1`
```

Then, you can use grep from the second file:

```
grep "${REF_IP}" file2
```

The result should be the line with the duplicated address.

Note: The actual syntax might be slightly different (I don't have access to a shell right now)

HTH

Comment: Yes I do its running debian 6.0.2. This comparison could be comparing over 30k ip's in each file.  The matches should be relatively low. under a 100 at at time.

Comment: @sectech The number of lines doesn't really matter; you'll have to read the file either way. Commands like `grep` have their own optimisations on file reading (in blocks). I guess in the end it depends what you do with the result... If you're processing it in a perl script, then you can rewrite the two commands above in a perl script.

Comment: Don't do this. See my comment in response to @sudo_Os post.

Comment: I see @sudo_Os post has been deleted and so so has my comment so just trust me - don't do this, it will easily result in false matches.

Answer (score 0):

take a look this oneliner, if it is what you want:

Note, this will print duplicated ip line in file2 only once. also assume there is no duplicated ips in file2.

```
 awk -F, 'NR==FNR{p[$1]=$0;next}{a[$0]++}END{for(x in a)if (a[x]>1)print p[x]}' file2 file1
```

little test:

```
kent$  head f1 f2
==> f1 <==
1.1.1.1
1.1.1.1
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2

==> f2 <==
1.1.1.1,Host TW,Taipei,25.0391998291,121.525001526
2.2.2.2,this is for 2.2.

kent$  awk -F, 'NR==FNR{p[$1]=$0;next}{a[$0]++}END{for(x in a)if (a[x]>1)print p[x]}' f2 f1
1.1.1.1,Host TW,Taipei,25.0391998291,121.525001526
```

Comment: Thanks Kent, so is this forgiving, Im trying to digest what you have wrote :)  so if there is say no space or host field has multiple identifiers will it still work? its not returning matches, and i have randomly added matches from file1 to file2.

Comment: it will work as long as 1, your requirement doesn't change, 2, in file2, format is `ip,foobarbla`

Comment: Ha so i recreated your f1 and f2 and of course it works :) im going to check for whitespaces..there must be something causing this to not print the dup. Thank you!

Comment: There must be something causing it to die..In the middle of both files i added "1.1.1.1" in f1  in f2 i added 1.1.1.1,Scanning Host RS,Pancevo,44.8708000183,20.6403007507  no matches!!??!???!!

Comment: @sectech the command is looking for duplicate lines WITHIN f1 and then printing the matching line from f2 which is probably not how you have your sample data files populated. Add a second line containing 1.1.1.1 to f1 to see what i mean.

Comment: @EdMorton you are right. :) I am not sure if I understood the question right. though. if his "duplicate" means "match", my answer was wrong.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I think @steve's got it right in his interpretation of the question and his answer.

Comment: yes sorry, sometimes whats in your head doesnt articulate on paper well. I did mean "match" instead of dup.